# How to print a line below something in a text file for an atm system

Tags: python

I am trying to create a system where the login is done through validating a name and password is present in one function, there is another function to view the balance but I cant quite work it out. I was thinking I could place the persons balance under the name and password in a text file and print the balance as the line number of the login + 1 however I can't get it to work.

My text file looks like this:

```
jack carruthers/2000
100
```

The name and password is separated by /. The 100 represents the balance

My current code is this:

```
# Jack Carruthers
# ATM 

file_path = "user_info.txt"

def login():
    x = True 
    while x == True:
        
        global line_num
        info = input("Enter login in format:\n Name/Pin \n") 
        with open(r"C:\T-Level Digital Production\Library\ATM\ATM\user_info.txt", "r") as fp:
            for line_num, line in enumerate(fp):       
                if (info) in line:
                    x = False
                    print("Login successful") 
                    
                    quest = input("Would you like to view your balance")  
                    if quest == "y":
                        balance()  
           
                           
                    elif quest == "n": # tbc
                        print("????????????????")
                        
                else:
                    print("Invalid login, please try again")
                    x = True

def balance(): 
    with open(r"C:\T-Level Digital Production\Library\ATM\ATM\user_info.txt", "r") as fp:
        print(format(line_num + 1))     

def withdraw():
    pass

def deposit():
    pass

def main():
    pass 

login()
```

I have tried doing things such as putting the line number for the user and password as a global variable and printing the line number + 1 however it doesn't seem to work. I have also searched the web for fixes, however none of them seem to work.

Comment: Here are some hints for you.  Store the file name in a string variable.  Don't type it over and over.  Consider having one function to read the file into a data structure, and another file to write out the data structure.  Now your code just deals with Python variables, and not files.

Answer (score 0):

Your balance function is just printing the current global line number and not the file line:

```
def balance(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as fp:
        lines = fp.readlines()
        balance = lines[1].strip() #read second line
        print("Your balance is:", balance)
```

It would be easier if you just read the whole file once and store the info in memory.

Comment: Hello, this does kind of resolve my problem but I forgot to mention I am gonna be using multiple user logins, so the balance would have to match the login above. Is there a way to make this possible?

Comment: Sure, if you are using one file per user, just have the file_name be the same as the user login and try and open each file on login.