# How to resolve multiple prints happening when I don't want them to on a ATM login system

Tags: python

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
jack carruthers/2006 
150 

oliver daniels/0000
10
```

The text above the numbers is what the user has to type to login, once successfully logged in the user will be able to do a range of tasks and the one I have a problem with at the moment is the balance showing. To confirm the numbers below login is the balance.
I haven't had any problems until I have added the second user.

When I log in as the second user it will still print the balance however it also prints invalid login and no matter what I do I can't seem to fix it.

My code:

```
# Jack Carruthers
# ATM 

file_path = "user_inf.txt"


def login():
    global line_num # Globalises line number so later on it can be used to read/alter users balance 
    info = input("Enter login in format:\n Name/Pin \n") 
    with open(r"C:\T-Level Digital Production\Library\atm_1\atm_1\user_inf.txt", "r") as fp: # File path for user info 
        
        for line_num, line in enumerate(fp):  # Assigns line_num variable to the process of outputting line numbers in text file 
            if (info) in line:  # if what the user inputted is present then 
                print("Login successful \n") 
                main() # Runs main program after successful login
                balance() 
                
                break  # break to avoid invalid login appearing 
                        
            else:
                print("Invalid login, please try again")

def balance():
    with open(r"C:\T-Level Digital Production\Library\atm_1\atm_1\user_inf.txt", "r") as fp:    
        lines = fp.readlines()
        global balances
        balances = lines[line_num + 1].strip() #read second line
        print("Your balance is: \n")
        print(balances, "GBP")


def withdraw():
    pass


def deposit():
    pass


def end():
    pass

def main():     
    pass


login()
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem occurring:

[image: Here is a screenshot of the problem occurring]

I have tried using different methods of reading the file for the login however it has not worked, I don't have a clue what else to try.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: You're printing an error on *each* line as you test it, not if you found it on *any* line. I'd suggest a `return` if you find it, and if the loop finishes, then print the error.

Comment: You should also think about structuring your functions so they return *data* and avoid side-effects like printing or calling other functions. Leave that up to the caller. For example, `try_login(credentials)` could perform *only* the login validity testing and return `True` or `False`.

Comment: Side note: if the user enters something like just "/" then `if (info) in line:` will be true for any line in the file that has a "/" in it.

Comment: As a bigger-picture design consideration, you probably want to only read the data file *once*, when the program starts, and keep the data in memory as a dictionary. You, can, of course, still *write* to it any time there's a change. Splitting it up so each user is a different file would mean a lot less file rewriting. (And as tadman said, please include the output as text, not an image.)

Comment: Expanding on @tadman's comment, to understand why you aren't getting what you want think about (or add some intermediate print statements to see) what is happening in your loop in the login method.  It reads the first line, does it match "oliver daniels/0000", no.  So it prints the Invalid login line and goes to the second line.  Again it doesn't match, and again Invalid login.  Same with the thrid line.  Then the fourth line matches.

Comment: Note for readers: this is related to [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77283204/how-to-print-a-line-below-something-in-a-text-file-for-an-atm-system).

Answer (score 0):

While I encourage you to switch to some other format that is easier to parse, this should get you going. You want to skip lines until you find a match and then process the match and `break`. You will then use the `else` clause of the `for` loop to handle the case that there was no `break`.

```py
        for line_num, line in enumerate(fp):
            if info.strip() != line.strip():
                continue

            print("Login successful \n") 
            main()
            balance() 
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid login, please try again")
```

This will get you past the issue with the `login()` but you still have a problem with `balance()`. let me see about fixing it as well....

Here is a more complete solution:

```py
# Jack Carruthers
# ATM 

file_path = "in.txt"

def login():
    info = input("Enter login in format:\n Name/Pin \n") 
    with open(file_path, "r") as fp:
        for line in fp:
            if info.strip() != line.strip():
                continue

            print("Login successful \n") 

            ## the "next" line in the file is our balance
            user_balance = int(next(fp).strip())
            main()
            balance(user_balance) 
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid login, please try again")

def balance(user_balance):
    print(f"Your balance is: {user_balance} GBP")

def withdraw():
    pass

def deposit():
    pass

def end():
    pass

def main():     
    pass

login()
```